# How to Send email using a SMTP sever in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, smtp, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I was tried to send emails using SMTP Sampler but not able to send. got below error with 500 Response code.

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587
```

[image]

Comment: What JMeter and JDK do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check connectivity from your machine to port `587` of the `smtp.gmail.com` host using [telnet client](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/5/Troubleshooting/Test_your_network_connection) or equivalent, you should see something like:

   ```
   Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g20sm1259543lfh.33 - gsmtp
   ```

   [image]

   If you will not be able to see the above output - maybe access to Gmail SMTP port is blocked by OS or router [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) so you will need to contact your network administrator in order to get the access
2. It might be the case your organisation is using a [corporate proxy](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/proxy-server) to access the Internet. If this is the case - you will not be able to use SMTP Sampler as it doesn't support proxy configuration, [especially if the authentication is required](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy). If this is the case - you will need to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write the logic of sending the email using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language.

   - [Download simple-java-mail-5.1.3.jar](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/simplejavamail/simple-java-mail/5.1.3/simple-java-mail-5.1.3.jar) and drop it to the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
   - [Download emailaddress-rfc2822-1.1.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/bbottema/emailaddress-rfc2822/1.1.2/emailaddress-rfc2822-1.1.2.jar) and drop it to the "lib" folder of your JMeter insatllation
   - Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
   - Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
   - Put the following code into "Script" area:

     ```
     import org.simplejavamail.email.Email
     import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder
     import org.simplejavamail.mailer.Mailer
     import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder
     import org.simplejavamail.mailer.config.TransportStrategy

     Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
             .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
             .withSMTPServer("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
             .withSMTPServerUsername("Your SMTP Username")
             .withSMTPServerPassword("Your SMTP Password")
             .withProxyHost("replace with your proxy host")
             .withProxyPort(1234) // replace with your proxy port
             .withProxyUsername("your proxy username if needed")
             .withProxyPassword("your proxy password if needed")
             .buildMailer()

     Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
             .from("SMTP FROM address (in the majority of cases the same as SMTP Username)")
             .to("Recipient")
             .withSubject("test script")
             .withPlainText("test message")
             .buildEmail()

     mailer.sendMail(email)
     ```